# Ionic rendering issue during swipe on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, ionic-framework, swipe

In the video below, a swipe to the right is happening. In the header section, the toolbar with `All/Classes/Products` lags behind the disappearance of the background image (is there a way to make the background image follow along with the swipe?) Also the yellow plus sign moves over about `40px` and then disappears after lagging behind the swipe/disappearance of the rest of the header.

My `ion-header` HTML looks like this:

```
<ion-header #ionheader (touchstart)="swipe($event, 'start')" (touchend)="swipe($event, 'end')"> <!--[@slideDown]="downState"-->
  <ion-toolbar #clickme class="itemadspace" [@slideDown]="downState" no-padding> <!--[@slideDown]="downState"-->
    <!--<ion-item class="ad" no-padding no-lines>-->
    <div class="stylistview">
      <button class="stylistviewbutton" (tap)='switchView()' ion-button color="secondary">User View</button>
    </div>

    <!--</ion-item>-->
  </ion-toolbar>

  <div (tap)="loadPost()" class='pluscontainer' [@plusSlide]="downState">
    <ion-icon class='plussy' name="add"></ion-icon>
  </div>

  <div class="clickme" (tap)="toolClicked($event)">
    <ion-navbar  color="black" [@toolSlide]="toolbarState" id="iontoolbar"> <!--[@toolSlide]="toolbarState"-->
      <ion-icon class='custom-icon' name="play"></ion-icon>
      <button class="all toolbarstyle" #allF ion-button color="black" (tap)="all()">All</button>
      <button class="classes toolbarstyle" #classesFeed ion-button color="black" (tap)="products()">Classes</button>
      <button class="products toolbarstyle" #productsFeed ion-button color="black" (tap)="classes()">Products</button>
    </ion-navbar>
  </div>
</ion-header>
```

CSS:

```
ion-toolbar {
        div.toolbar-background {
            background-image: url('../img/tresemme.png') !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;

        }
    }

.itemadspace {
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        text-align: center;
        height: 88px;
    }

.pluscontainer {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        right: 10px;
        top: 28px;
    }

.plussy {
        font-size: 72px;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: map-get($colors, primary);
        /*position: relative;*/
    }

.toolbarstyle {
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 0 0.5em;
        color: gray;
        background-color: black;
    }

#iontoolbar {
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        top: 88px;
        left: 0;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-bottom-color: map-get($colors, primary);
        border-bottom-width: 4px;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Comment: In my  (admittedly not gigantic) experience with animation, the most likely culprit is that one item is being calculated wider than the other at some point. 

And oddly enough, the width of your plus sign and the offset of that bar might end up being the same number. 

Sorry I cant help code-wise, but just offering up my observation

EDIT: It looks like your header gets collapsed in the animation, is that pushing the plus down causing the bar to slide out too far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe problem here is that both the `#iontoolbar` and .pluscontainer has the CSS positioning `absolute`.

And sometimes running transitions on absolute and fixed positioned elements will cause the elements to appear as if they're lagging behind. And they become even more choppy when nested.

To be honest, I don't know the exact details as to why this is happening, but in my own experience this is worst in mobile safari. I would suggest you make some adjustments to your HTML and CSS structure. There's no reason in my humble opinion as to why these elements should have `position: absolute;` at all, but can be easily done with relative positioning.

Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: I got the toolbar not to lag by putting a container `<div>` just inside `<ion-header>` containing the rest of the code and it doesn't lag. I tried your suggestion anyway...and your solution does help with the lag...but lots of other things start going wrong if i make the changes to `position`. A lot of whitespace gets added in between the toolbar and the list...i also have `swipeleft` `swiperight` in the `div`

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Ionic to be honest, but you also could make use of jquery.transit to make the animations even smoother. I don't do anything on mobile without jquery.transit. Makes the animations as smooth as VKWebview permits. Also, what library are you using for the slider?

Comment: I just had to change some animation values and it works...thanks!

Comment: Great! glad I could help you.