# Swipe animation lags - ionic / css

Tags: html, css, animation, ionic-framework, swipe

Here is what is happening:

[image]

I have had this problem before, and had it successfully answered:

[Ionic rendering issue during swipe on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490772/ionic-rendering-issue-during-swipe-on-ios)

But this page is built very slightly differently...and even after taking out all the `position: absolute`'s in the header (where the lagging css is), as suggested correctly in my question above, it still lags. Are there any other reasons this could be happening?

Here is my code:

**Header HTML**

```
<ion-header> <!--[@slideDown]="downState"-->
  <div (swiperight)="swipeRight()" (swipeleft)="swipeLeft()">
    <ion-toolbar #clickme class="itemadspace" [@slideDown]="downState" no-padding> <!--[@slideDown]="downState"-->
      <!--<ion-item class="ad" no-padding no-lines>-->
      <div class="stylistview">
        <button class="stylistviewbutton" (tap)='switchView()' ion-button color="secondary">User View</button>
      </div>

      <swiper #swiper [config]="config" [(index)]="swiperIndex" (indexChange)="indexChange()">
        <div *ngFor="let ad of ads; let i = index" class="adcontainer">
          <img src="{{ad}}" class="adimage" #adimage>
        </div>
      </swiper>
    </ion-toolbar>

    <!--</ion-item>-->
    <div class='pluscontainer' [@plusSlide]="downState">
      <p>BUY</p><br><p>AD</p>
    </div>

    <div class="clickme" (tap)="toolClicked($event)">
      <ion-navbar  color="black" [@toolSlide]="toolbarState" id="iontoolbar"> <!--[@toolSlide]="toolbarState"-->
        <ion-icon class='custom-icon' name="play"></ion-icon>
        <button class="all toolbarstyle" #allF ion-button color="black" (tap)="all()">All</button>
        <button class="classes toolbarstyle" #classesFeed ion-button color="black" (tap)="classes()">Classes</button>
        <button class="products toolbarstyle" #productsFeed ion-button color="black" (tap)="products()">Products</button>
        <button class="formulas toolbarstyle" #formulasFeed ion-button color="black" (tap)="formulasList()">Formulas</button>
      </ion-navbar>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-header>
```

**Related CSS**

```
.itemadspace {
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

.stylistviewbutton {    
    font-size: 12px;
}

.stylistview {
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 24%;
    z-index: 5;
    width:5%;
}

.adcontainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.adimage {
    width: auto;
}

.pluscontainer {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 0px;
    top: 60px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    color: map-get($colors, primary);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
}

#iontoolbar {
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: map-get($colors, primary);
    border-bottom-width: 4px;
}

.custom-icon {
    color : gray;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

.all {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.toolbarstyle {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    color: gray;
    background-color: black;
}

.toolbarstyle:focus {
    color: map-get($colors, primary);
}

ion-toolbar {
    div.toolbar-background {
        //background-image: url('../img/tresemme.png') !important;
    //background-repeat: no-repeat;
        //background-size: cover;
        background-color: #000000;
    }
}

swiper.s-wrapper>.swiper .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide, swiper.s-wrapper>.swiper .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide-content {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 77%;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
    height: 300px;
}
```

I also found this which gets used by the header...and it has `position: absolute` - could this be messing everything up?

```
ion-header {
  @include position(0, null, null, 0);

  position: absolute;
  z-index: $z-index-toolbar;
  display: block;

  width: 100%;
}
```

I have tried without the `position: absolutes/fixed`, I replaced some with `position: relative` - but it didn't help. Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the ionic-WKWebview  and verify that your animation is working properly . you can get the ionic wkwebview from [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview#installation-instructions) . Most of the UI Issues might resolved by using the above plugin .

**Update:** From your comment you mentioned that

> the animation is just the animation used when you pass options to the
>   nav controller to animate a page change...the lag should just be the
>   page swiping fluidly

yes, and in your question you didn't mention how you are animating through navcontroller, if haven't used that way , then this is the another way to set the animation

```
 var navOptions = {
      animation: 'ios-transition'
 };
 this.navController.push(yourpagename, null, navOptions);
```

Comment: im giving it a shot now...i think according to the instructions all I have to do is install it...is that right?

Comment: i ran `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview --save` and did prepare and it is still lagging

Comment: the animation is just the animation used when you pass options to the nav controller to animate a page change...the lag should just be the page swiping fluidly

Comment: @ewizard it would be better if you can update the question , how it is looking after you adding the plugin

Comment: it looks the same...the plugin didnt really help with the lagging animation...it just seemed to help a little with the smoothness...maybe nothing changed

Comment: with your navoptions suggestion...i also need to control whether it loads forwards or backwards because the app uses swiping...im assuming ios-transition doesnt pick up on which way you are swiping...and loads from the same direction every time